# Flex-grow behaves inconsistently across browsers with subunit or fractional values

Tags: css, cross-browser, flexbox, percentage

Safari, Chrome and Firefox have different results for the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box-1"></div>
    <div class="box-2"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 1000px;
}
.box-1 {
    flex: 0.5 0.5 0;
}
.box-2 {
    flex: 0.3 0.3 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/andreiduca/pen/ybOwWV

Both boxes have a flex basis of `0`. This means the remaining available space is `1000px`.

**Expected result:**

The sum of all the grow factors is `0.5 + 0.3 = 0.8` so the remaining available space will be divided as `1000px / 0.8 = 1250px`.

Each box will get a portion of that space based on their grow factor:

- `.box-1` will get `1250px * 0.5 = 625px`
- `.box-2` will get `1250px * 0.3 = 375px`

The total width of the boxes is `625 + 375 = 1000px`, filling the entire `.container`. Safari gets this right.

**Actual result:**

Chrome and Firefox will divide the remaining space by a minimum factor of `1`, and never `0.8`. So the remaining available space is `1000px / round(0.8) = 1000px`.

Then again, each box will get a portion of that space based on their grow factor:

- `.box-1` will get `1000px * 0.5 = 500px`
- `.box-2` will get `1000px * 0.3 = 300px`

The total width of the boxes is `500 + 300 = 800px`, NOT filling the entire `.container`. We are left with an undistributed space of `200px`.

So the question is: which browser gets it right, and why?

Comment: I think you misread a little, or you don't see an issue that the available space should be 1250px for an element that is 1000px?

Comment: How does this one look on Safari: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbaNjR

Comment: According to the specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#resolve-flexible-lengths, **9.7. Resolving Flexible Lengths** paragraph **4** point **b** says "If the sum of the unfrozen flex items’ flex factors is less than one, multiply the initial free space by this sum [and] use this as the remaining free space" which is even weirder. As I understand, the remaining free space should be `1000px * 0.8 = 800px` and then the boxes will be `800 * 0.5 = 400px` and `800 * 0.3 = 240px` having a total sum of `400 + 240 = 640px`.

Comment: Chrome https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9ifb6sp33j5cub/Screenshot%202017-04-21%2015.15.45.png?dl=0 vs Safari https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxj8dgl9bc2umqn/Screenshot%202017-04-21%2015.15.48.png?dl=0

Comment: @LGSon I believe the `1250px` is the calculated intrinsic width of the container: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#intrinsic-sizes. So yes, I don't see any problems with that value.

Comment: Nope, the initial/remaining available space is what's left when you subtract the sum the outer sizes of all flex items from the flex container’s inner main size, which is 1000px - 0px = 1000px. Now, from there your items will take 0.5 resp. 0.3 (total of 0.8) multiplied with 1000px, equals 800px. So Safari (and IE11) does this wrong and Chrome/Firefox/Edge does this right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @LGSon answer and after reading the specs 100 times more: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#remaining-free-space

- **only the *remaining* free space is distributed**, which in this case, because the sum of all the flex-grow factors is less than 1, is calculated from the *initial* free space multiplied by the sum of the factors: `1000px * 0.8 = 800px`
- each flex box will receive the remaining free space multiplied by the **proportion of their flex-grow value to the total sum of all flex-grow values**

So `.box-1` will get `800px * 0.5 / 0.8 = 500px`; likewise, `.box-2` is  `800px * 0.3 / 0.8 = 300px`. The rest of `200px` is left undistributed.

Safari 10.1 is missing this calculation, but SafariTP gets it right.